at make 3d play at ursina my enemies dont movement in play
althuogh i definition to corecce create and movement  for enemies  at game but it  dont show enemies and but  if  it show the enemies but enemies  dont movement what do i should   enemies  make movement at  game What can I do to make enemies move in the game?
enemies = []
for i in range(4):
    # Create an instance of the enemy character
    enemy = FrameAnimation3d(
        'ArtStation - Stylized Anatomy BASEMESHESo/3D Model character Ghoul.obj',
        fps=10,
        scale=(0.02, 0.02, 0.02),
        position=(0, -4),
        texture = 'Jowhareh_galleries_7_poster_0c03a8fa-b5b4-4815-9a32-bc830b07ff58.png'
        
    )

    # Create an asobject entity as a child of the enemy entity
    asobject = Entity(
        model = 'ArtStation - Stylized Anatomy BASEMESHESo/3D Model character Ghoul.obj',
        parent=enemy,
        texture = 'Jowhareh_galleries_7_poster_0c03a8fa-b5b4-4815-9a32-bc830b07ff58.png',
        scale=(0.02, 0.02, 0.02),
# position=(0, -4),

